# Visual Studio Cordova target Windows 10 not possible anymore

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I recently reinstalled Visual Studio 2015 and suddenly, in my cordova projects, the possibility to target Windows 10 is gone: Only Windows 8.1 can be chosen as a target in the dropdown box.

Before reinstallation:
[image]

After reinstallation:
[image]

This is my VS2015 setup:
[image]

Can someone tell me what is going on?

Comment: Have you checked the Cordova CLI version setting of config.xml? In order to target windows 10,it needs to be 5.1.1 or later.

Comment: Yes, my CLI version is 5.3.3. I've also tried 5.1.1 but no difference. When I try to manually enter <preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" /> in my config.xml and press build, I can see in my console that the message "No UAP SDK exists on this machine" comes up right before the build process exits with errors. Which is weird, because I have a Windows 10 SDK installed on my machine. Maybe, a path to the SDK is not set correctly?

Comment: Just an addition: When I try to manually install the Windows 10 SDK from here https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk, this is the screen I see after I run the installer: http://s32.postimg.org/ma3jv8mv9/4r34r43r3w.png

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it: I went to Settings > System > Apps & Features and uninstalled Windows Software Development Kit 10.0.10586.212.

Then I went to https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive, downloaded the older SDK 10.0.26624.0 and installed it and now Windows 10 is back as a target version!